# Erro CORS ocorre para um endpoint da API, mas não para outro

Tags: react, django

Eu tenho uma API REST escrita em DRF. Um aplicativo react consome esta API usando:

```js
export default function Body() {
    const location = useLocation();
    const searchQuery = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("q");
    const [offices, setOffices] = useState([]);

  useEffect(function () {
    async function fetchData() {
      const baseUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL;
      // let apiUrl = `${baseUrl}/api/search/offices/insurance`;
      let apiUrl = `${baseUrl}/api/office/office/`;

      if (searchQuery) {
        apiUrl += `${encodeURIComponent(searchQuery)}`;
      }


      const res = await fetch(apiUrl);
      const full_object = await res.json();
      const data = full_object.results;

      console.log(data);
      setOffices(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [searchQuery]);

  return (
    <main className="menu">
      <ul className="offices">
        {offices &&
          offices.map((office) => (
            <Office officeObj={office} key={office.id} />
          ))}
      </ul>
    </main>
  );
}
```

O problema é: o endpoint `${baseUrl}/api/office/office/` funciona normalmente. Enquanto o `${baseUrl}/api/search/offices/insurance` falha com CORS e erro 301:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/api/search/offices/insurance. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 301
```

As configurações de CORS no servidor parecem corretas. Para o ambiente de desenvolvimento, eu fiz:

```py
#settings
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'corsheaders',
    # ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    # ...
]

ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

O que pode, então, estar causando o erro de CORS nesse caso?

Comment: pra mim parece o mesmo endpoint. Em que caso ocorre o erro 301?

Comment: perdão. Eu cometi um erro de digitação na pergunta. Acabei de corrigir. São endpoints diferentes. O endpoint de search não funciona. O erro 301 vem na mensagem do browser, que também adicionei na pergunta.

Comment: poderia tentar novamente, adicionando uma barra no final do endpoint de `insurrance`. A correção ficaria assim: `${baseUrl}/api/search/offices/insurance/`

Comment: @Danizavtz muito obrigado. Isso resolveu. Aparentemnte, isso está relacionado a uma forma específica com que o o Django trata url sem a barra no final: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/middleware/common.py#L62 . Se achar que vale uma resposta explicando isso, pode redigir que dou o aceite.

Comment: Sem problema, já passei algumas vezes por este problema. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta é uma configuração do Django, e este comportamento é documentado e eu destaquei a parte importante. Segundo a documentação

> APPEND_SLASH DEFAULT: true. Quando definido como True, se o URL da solicitação não corresponder a nenhum dos padrões no URLconf e não terminar com uma barra, um redirecionamento HTTP será emitido para o mesmo URL com uma barra anexada (é feito um append da barra, ao final da URL). **Observe que o redirecionamento pode causar a perda de quaisquer dados enviados em uma solicitação POST.**

[fonte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash)

Desta forma, para evitar este problema, basta adicionar a barra no final do endpoint em que está ocorrendo o redirect 301.

```
#Codigo que gera o redirect 301
let apiUrl = `${baseUrl}/api/search/offices/insurance`
----------------------------
#Correção
let apiUrl = `${baseUrl}/api/search/offices/insurance/`
                                                     ^ adicionar esta barra no URL
```

Outra opção é desativar esta opção `APPEND_SLASH`.

Para desativar a opção `APPEND_SLASH` deve declarar no `settings.py` setando o seu valor para `False`. já que o default é `True` em geral este atributo não está declarado no `settings.py`